# Show $\frac{3997}{4001}>\frac{4996}{5001}$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

I wish to show that $$\frac{3997}{4001}>\frac{4996}{5001}.$$

Of course, with a calculator, this is incredibly simple. But is there anyway of showing this through pure analysis? So far, I just rewrote the fractions:

$$\frac{4000-3}{4000+1}>\frac{5000-4}{5000+1}.$$

Comment: Try subtracting each of the two fractions from 1, and comparing the results.

Comment: The obvious way to do this is writing the fractions with a common denominator. The computations are simple enough to do without a calculator. Do you want a more elegant solution? If so, you should clearly specify that in your question.

Comment: Why did you round to the thousands. 3997/4001 = 1 - 4/4001.  4996/5001 = 1 - 5/5001.  4/4001 = 1/1000.25.  But 5/5001 = 1/1000.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing with your approach, write

$\frac{4000(1-3/4000)}{4000(1+1/4000)}>\frac{5000(1-4/5000)}{5000(1+1/5000)}$

Then cancel on both sides and cross multiply:

$(1-\frac{3}{4000})(1+\frac{1}{5000})>(1+\frac{1}{4000})(1-\frac{4}{5000})$

Now, expand both sides:

$1+\frac{1}{5000}-\frac{3}{4000}-\frac{3}{20000000}>1+\frac{1}{4000}-\frac{4}{5000}-\frac{4}{20000000}$

$\frac{5}{5000}-\frac{4}{4000}+\frac{1}{20000000}>0$

$\frac{1}{20000000}>0$.

Since the above is clearly true, then the original statement is true also.

Comment: @user320276 not really, there's several similar ways to do it depending on which way you do even out the math first.

Answer (score 11):

Subtract $1$ from both sides:

$$-\frac{4}{4001} > -\frac{5}{5001}$$

Remove the negatives and flip the inequality:

$$\frac{4}{4001} < \frac{5}{5001}$$

This is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{1000.25} < \frac{1}{1000.2}$$

Multiply both sides by $1000.25 \cdot 1000.2$ to get

$$1000.2 < 1000.25$$

Since this is true, the original inequality must be true.

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You robbed OP of the joy of discovering some of this on his/her own.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Would you prefer that I write "spoiler alert" halfway through my answer?

Comment: I would prefer that you just give the hint, "subtract 1 from both sides", and then step back and see what OP can do. As I did.

Comment: I like this answer; I typically avoid decimals in my work, but this makes a good use of them :) I would still have preferred to "cross multiply" --- +$1$

Comment: @Clayton the decimals are kind of just lazy writing here. $1000 + \frac14$ and $1000+\frac15$ would keep the main idea better than 1000.25 and 1000.2 IMO.

Comment: IMO, no you did nothing wrong, please continue providing good answers, +1

Comment: Oh, horrors.  A person asked a question and another had the *gall* to answer it.  That's a down vote for sure...  sheesh...

Comment: I like your answer because it shows the difference is related to how proportional a remainder 1 is in n/(n*1000 + 1)

Comment: @djechlin: Oh, I completely agree, but it doesn't change the fact for me that I like to see approaches other than mine. I almost always tell my students to avoid decimals because they only obscure the picture. That isn't entirely the case with the question asked here as this answer demonstrates (still prefer my method :) ).

Answer (score 6):

First a minor but cute detour.

$a_n=\frac {n}{n*1000 +1} = \frac 1{1000 + 1/n} $.

As $n $ gets larger $1/n $ gets smaller, so $a_n $ get larger.  So $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 <.... $.

So $\frac {3997}{4001} = 1 - \frac 4 {4001} = 1 - a_4 > 1 - a_5 = 1 - \frac 5 {5001}=\frac {4996}{5001} $.

Okay, this wasn't as straightforward or as easy as the others but in my opinion it was i) informative as *why* it ought to be true and ii) cute.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to some other posts, but I find it a little simpler and easier, and does not have fractions.

$$\frac {4000-3} {4000+1} \gt \frac {5000-4} {5000+1}$$

Multiply by $({4000+1})*({5000+1)}$

$$({4000-3})*({5000+1}) \gt ({5000-4})*({4000+1})$$

Subtract 20,000,000 ($5000*4000$)
Subtract 5000
Subtract 4000

$$-3-(4*5000) \gt -4-(5*4000)$$

Add 20000
$$-3 \gt -4$$

Comment: This is my favorite answer, +1

Answer (score 2):

For positive real $a,b,c,d$, $\frac ab > \frac cd$ if and only if $ad - bc > 0$.

So cross multiplication is the key.

What you should compute is $(4000-3)(5000+1) - (5000-4)(4000+1)$.

Expand to get:

$(4000)(5000) - 3(5000) + 1(4000) - 3 - (5000)(4000) + 4(4000) - 1(5000) + 4$

and note that $(4000)(5000) - (5000)(4000) = 0$ (cancellation)

leaving you with:

$ - 3(5000) + 1(4000)  + 4(4000) - 1(5000) + 1$

after a little simplification, and which becomes:

$5(4000) - 4(5000) + 1$

after some grouping of terms and it's trivial to see that that becomes $1$.

Comment: No, could you elaborate further?

Comment: @user320276 You need to work out $(3997)(5001) - (4996)(4001)$. If that's positive then so is the result of the original subtraction between the fractions. You've already figured out how to express those large numbers in the form of $(4000-3)$, $(5000+1)$ and so forth. This is just building on that, using algebraic symbols to help clarification. Why don't you expand that expression I wrote and see what you get?

Comment: It is possible, Deepak, that OP has not done any algebra yet, and doesn't know from $x$s and $y$s.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, I see. OK, I'll edit it to remove the symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Using [long multiplication](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongMultiplication.html) we get
$$3997\times5001=19988997>19988996=4996\times4001$$
which implies the desired result (because positive multiplication preserves order).

Comment: Quite amazing how close they are!

Answer (score 2):

For all $n>0$, assume

$$\frac{4n-3}{4n+1}>\frac{5n-4}{5n+1}$$
$$(4n-3)(5n+1)>(4n+1)(5n-4)$$
$$20n^2-11n-3>20n^2-11n-4$$
$$-3>-4$$

which is true.

Answer (score 2):

Begin by observing that $\frac{3996}{4000}=\frac{4995}{5000}$, and think of these fractions as $\frac{\mbox{wins}}{\mbox{games played}}$ for chess players $A$ ($3996$ wins) and $B$ ($4995$ wins). One additional win will do more to improve player $A$’s win percentage than it will player $B$’s.